# APN - Error while sending background update notification with FCM

Tags: firebase, apple-push-notifications, firebase-cloud-messaging, google-cloud-functions, firebase-admin

I'm trying to send a silent notification with FCM and Admin functions.
That's my function:

```
exports.testNotification = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {

   let token = req.query.token;

    let message = {
        data: {
            data1: 'extra1',
            data2: 'extra2'
        },
        apns: {
            headers: {
                'apns-priority': '10',
                'apns-expiration': '0'
            },
            payload: {
                aps: {
                    'content-available': 1
                },
                'acme1' : 'bar'
            }
        },
        token: token
    };

    admin.messaging().send(message).then((response) => {
        res.status(200).send('OK');
    }).catch((error) => {
        res.status(200).send(error); --DISPLAY ERROR HERE
    });
});
```

I got this error

```
{"code":"messaging/invalid-argument","message":"Request contains an invalid argument."}
```

If I set badge or sound to the 'aps' dictionary it works:

```
aps: {
    'content-available': 1,
    badge:4
},
```

In [Apple developer guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/CreatingtheNotificationPayload.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH10-SW8), Listing 7-1 is the same as my test, that is without badge or sound.

I do not need the sound or the badge, I have to send a notification with "data" value (extra1, extra2), retrieve them and then be able to create a local notification that uses its.
Badge and sound are custom for every end-users, I can't set its in notification payload.

Comment: Try `contentAvailable: true` as the property.

Comment: "aps" i have to insert native APN key, not custom Firebase alias...I'll try and I'll tell you if it worked.

Comment: The Admin SDK expects it to be `contentAvailable: true`. Anything else will be removed, which in your case means the SDK sends out an empty `aps` dictionary (this behavior should probably be improved in the SDK). See the [API documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/admin.messaging.Aps#contentAvailable).